# Additional author causes biblatex to ignore maxcitenames

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I have 2 books and in the latter one an additional author is added. This somehow causes my set maxcitename in the options for biblatex to be ignored. In the attached picture you can see how it looks like now. I would like the second book to adhere to my maxcitename option. I thought it would be related to this question: [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex) but the answer did not change anything for me.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, maxbibnames=10]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hartung.2007,
 author = {Hartung, Joachim and Elpelt, B{\"a}rbel},
 year = {2007},
 title = {Multivariate Statistik: Lehr- und Handbuch der angewandten Statistik},
}
@book{Hartung.2009,
 author = {Hartung, Joachim and Elpelt, B{\"a}rbel and Kl{\"o}sener, Karl-Heinz},
 year = {2009},
 title = {Statistik: Lehr- und Handbuch der angewandten Statistik},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}    
\cite{Hartung.2007}
\cite{Hartung.2009}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: CurrentOutput]

instead of the 3 names appearing I want this: "Hartung et. al. (2009)"

Comment: Please have a look at http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/12997/biblatex-nur-erst-author-mit-et-al-im-text

Comment: Why are all brakets escaped in your example? Please fix that.

Comment: I have made your MWE compilable (I kicked out irrelevant code for the question in the process). Have you tried `uniquelist=minyear` or `uniquelist=false`, it worked fine for me. Incidentally, this is exactly the solution in the question you linked to (see the [third MWE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69030/35864)).

Comment: Any news here? As the questions is currently, it is a blatant duplicate of the very question you linked to. The solution there also seems to work. So we really need more details to investigate this.

Comment: Sorry I kind of overlooked this (was really busy). Uniquelist does not change anything for me but minyear is exactly what I needed. I don't think my linked question is a solution for my question. Either I am blind but I don't see the answer there mentioning minyear. It only mentions Uniquelist (which does not work for me) and maxcitename, which is not what I need here besides it is already set in the options.

Comment: OK, the answer does not mention `minyear` explicitly, but technically `uniquelist=false` should be even more rigorous in doing what you want than `minyear`. Though your question is not about `biblatex-apa` [this here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67961/35864) seems to be a good duplicate (it mentions `minyear` as well).

Comment: Would you mind if I voted to close your question here as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67961/35864?

Comment: nope go ahead. It is duplicate so that makes perfectly sense. :)

Comment: Fine, I'll do that then.